# Run-Time Check Failure #2 with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to make a manual string in c and

this code works:

```
int main() {
    char S = 'b';
    char* a = &S;
    char T = 'a';
    char *b = &T;
    *b = 'r';
}
```

But this one doesn't:

```
int main() {
    char S = 'b';
    char* a = &S;
    char *b = a + 1;
    *b = 'r';
}
```

(note that this code isn't supposed to make a string. I'm just including the part that gives me an exception.)

I get the exception "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'S' was corrupted".
Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: `char *b = a + 1;` Where do you expect `a+1` to point to?

Comment: I thought it points next to the memory address of a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code

```
int main() {
    char S = 'b';
    char* a = &S;
    char *b = a + 1;
    *b = 'r';
}
```

`S` has room for only one character, so "an element after `S`", which `b` points at, is invalid place to read or write something. (only creating this pointer is valid and it is useful to use as end of iteration)

`*b = 'r';` is doing writing to the invalid place, and fortunately your system detected the error.